# Java Regexp discussion

Tags: java, regex

I have this text that looks like this :

```
executeRule(document, 'SendEmail', [
    'emailAddress':'EMAIL(john@yahoo.com)',
    'subject':'Test',
    'text':'Test',
    'defaultText':'Test']
);
```

I need to parse it with a regexp in order to get the parameters for the executeRule.

Currently my regexp looks like this(java) :

```
List<String> partialRules = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> rules = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("executeRule\\(\\s*\\w+,\\s*'(\\w+)'\\s*,\\.*");
```

The problem is I can not find a regexp that will match my 3'rd parameter of the executeRule method.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)executeRule\\(\\s*?(.+?),\\s*?('.+?'),\\s*(\\[.+?\\])");
```

If i right understand what you want. Each argument will be save in group(i) of Matcher.

Comment: You cannot use split by commas, because third argument contains its.

Comment: How can I capture even the ; at the end of the method ? As of now the I match the entire method except for the final ; .

Thank you

Comment: If I right understand you want get entire method, not only arguments.
Try such code 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)executeRule\\(\\s*?(.+?),\\s*?('.+?'),\\s*(\\[.+?\\]\\s\\);)");

Comment: The pattern doesn't seem to compile to get my entire method :(

Comment: I check expression on your example. Could you show the regex part of code or may be some differents exist between example and real datas?

Comment: Well, I can't get the pattern set-up because I get "invalid escape sequence" after executeRule ... there`s only one \ . If I replace all \ with \\ I get the pattern running but doesn't match my text

Comment: This is an accepted pattern by Java :
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\.](?s)executeRule\\(\\s*?(.+?),\\s*?('.+?'),\\s*(\\[.+?\\]\\s\\);)");

but it doesn't match my string(which is as in the above examaple).

Comment: I finally got it working. The correct expression is : 
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\.](?s)executeRule\\(\\s*?(.+?),\\s*?('.+?'),\\s*(\\[.+?\\]\\s*\\);)");

Comment: It was my mistake. Forgot to escape all slashes. Pattern.compile("(?s)executeRule\\(\\s*?(.+?),\\s*?('.+?'),\\s*(\\[.+?\\]\\s\\);)");
Hm.. it's not my error, error of message parser. Check all slashes. I don't know how hear to write a raw string.

Remove [^\\.] before (?s). (?s) is a flag to include whitespace in dot and nothing must be before it.

Comment: How could I capture the strings that look like this : 
executeRule(document, 'SendEmail', []
);

too ? 

I mean, there might be some strings that have nothing in between [] 

Thank you !

Comment: (\[.+?\]\\s\);)"); replace plus to multiplication
(\[.*?\]\\s\);)");

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work only if the pattern is [ ] (with a space in between the [] ); but my pattern is [] with nothing in between.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Are you want [] empty brackets but \\[.*?\\] don't work?

Comment: Yes, I want empty brackets [] but it seems \[.*?\] doesn't capture the pattern :|

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had to replace in 2 places. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought of not using one regexp to do all the above, but writing a simple parser to split on commas, then delegating to another parser to parse each colon-delimited pair? It may be easier to construct/debug (depending on whether you allow commas within each text string, of course).

If you choose to expand your above syntax, then this may well be more extensible than one (possibly sizable) regexp.

Comment: Absolutely! Since you know you will have exactly x arguments and they will be comma-separated and there should be no commas in the arguments, this seems like a really nice solution rather than an overly complex regex.

Comment: The executeRule method can occur more than one time in my text and in between these executeRule methods there can be unrelated text(e.g. 
text text
executeRule(X, Y, Z);
text text
executeRule(X, Y, Z);

Comment: one of my fav quote - Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.